# why eclipse shortcut doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, plugins, keyboard, ocaml, shortcut

I'm using Juno on macOSX mountain lion. <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> doesn't close editor windows, but it gives 'put breakpoint' for some Ocaml plugins. This is strange because I can't find anything OCaml in my plugins, neither from **Help->Install New Software->already installed**, nor the folders in the filesystem. I must have had the plugin before but already removed it.

**Preferences->General->keys** shows the right binding (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> means closing and NO conflict), but it doesn't work. If I change it to another binding, that will work. But <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is convenient.

The weird thing is that after removing `~/Library/Cache and ~/Library/Preferences` for eclipse and installing a fresh copy, the problem persists. This is what drives me crazy.

Does anybody know what is the problem? What else can I remove to set eclipse to factory default?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I tried to use another workspace and it worked fine. So I found in my current workspace a .metadata/.plugins folder and removed that. That was the reason.

Caution: this resets everything and removes all plugins.

Comment: Well, I did this and it removed the workspace basically, so I have to import everything again.